# Do QueryInterface calls from aggregating COM objects to aggregated objects need special handling?

Tags: com, aggregation

These days its much harder to find decent documentation compared to 10 years ago, so I'm gonna try my luck and see if anyone remembers the rules of aggregation because the MSDN docs aren't clear on it. In particular I'm questioning the [following rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/aggregation#aggregating-objects) for the outer (aggregating) objects:

> The outer object must call its controlling IUnknown Release method if it queries for a pointer to any of the inner object's interfaces. To free this pointer, the outer object calls its controlling IUnknown AddRef method, followed by Release on the inner object's pointer.

and it has a code sample

```
// Obtaining inner object interface pointer 
pUnkInner->QueryInterface(IID_ISomeInterface, &pISomeInterface); 
pUnkOuter->Release(); 

// Releasing inner object interface pointer 
pUnkOuter->AddRef(); 
pISomeInterface->Release();
```

My question being: is that necessary? what scenario is it protecting against? how do you implement it when the pointer lives longer than a method call?

In particular I'm wondering, if the aggregating object exposes its inner objects interfaces (which is the whole point of aggregation), how is it going to perform this reference counting dance? If the aggregating object returns an interface to the inner object to its callers it passes ownership of the reference, it won't know when the caller is done with it, and the caller won't know he is dealing with an aggregate.

(I *think* this question should be self contained, but having people complain previously when I asked questions without concrete code, if you really need me to provide sample code of the aggregating class I'm working on for answering that I can add that. IMHO it shouldn't be necessary and doesn't add any value to the question, it is pretty standard COM and I'm just asking about the rules here.)

Comment: The text is in the context of an outer object obtaining access to an inner interface for its own private use. Since the inner object will forward its `AddRef` back out to the outer object (see `CImpSomeInterface::AddRef`), if you didn't do a `punkOuter->Release()`, you would create a circular reference.

If the result of the QI is going to be handed out, then the person you hand it to will do a Release which will balance the AddRef created by the forwarded QI, and everything will be fine.

Comment: @RaymondChen I see, that does make sense, thank you! I assume the dance for releasing is then mostly for bookkeeping purposes and symmetry? Considering the inner interface will forward the Release to the outer object anyways.

Comment: As noted, the discussion is in the context of the object obtaining and caching a pointer to its own inner object. If you don't follow the QI with a Release, you will end up with a circular reference and thereby end up leaking.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I understood that part thanks to your explanation before, was talking about the second half "Releasing inner object interface pointer". With your explanation it looks like a no-op (AddRef on outer followed by forwarded Release), except that maybe the inner objects interface Release, besides forwarding to the outer objects Release, may be doing some logging which wouldn't be symmetric otherwise? I'm not wanting to omit it, just making sure I understand the scenario correctly.